# how to add reportviewer control in visual studio 2017 vb .net

Tags: visual-studio-2017, reportviewer

how to add reportviewer control in visual studio 2017?
controls are installed

but I cant into vb .net  application forms

control only showing below the from 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycTwr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method above still can not add the report viewer control to the toolbox, then try to drag the dll directly to the toolbox:

1, open Windows explorer and navigate to the DLL

2, drag the DLL and drop it on Visual Studio in the Toolbox, exactly where you want your components to appear

{Solution Directory}
This means working project folder
C:\Users\xxxx\xxxx\repos\WindowsApp4
For example this  the project location means
Get into following path:
C:\Users\xxxx\xxxx\repos\WindowsApp4\packages
C:\Users\xxxx\xxxx\repos\WindowsApp4\packages\Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms.140.340.80
C:\Users\xxxx\xxxx\repos\WindowsApp4\packages\Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms.140.340.80\lib
C:\Users\xxxx\xxxx\repos\WindowsApp4\packages\Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms.140.340.80\lib\net40
Under this folder Following is the dll.

*Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll*

Drag and drop the above mentioned dll to tool box

Answer (score 0):

Step 1, run the following command in the Package Manager Console:
***Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms -***Version 140.340.80

Step 2, Remove the ReportViewer Control that is listed in the toolbox. This is the control with a version of 12.x.

Step 3, Right click in anywhere in the toolbox and then select Choose Items....

Step 4, On the .NET Framework Components, select Browse.

Step 5, Select the Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll from the NuGet package you installed.
The NuGet package will be installed in the solution directory of your project. The path to the dll will be similar to the following: 
{Solution Directory}\packages\Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms.{version}\lib\net40
Step 6, The new control should display within the toolbox.